# OpenERP 7, accounting module

Tags: python, odoo, accounting, access-rights

I need to create a group of users who are allowed only to see supplier Invoices and not customer invoices (in accounting module).

I'm asking if it is possible to do that and if yes how can I do it please?

PS:I've done a couple of search but I did not find any thing that may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a rule:

```
<record id="your_rule_id" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">Rule Name</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_account_invoice"/>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(6,0, [ref('your_group')])]"/>
    <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="False"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[('your_field','=','supplier')]</field>
</record>
```

I hope this help you.